# Trouble updating a date in MongoDB via Mongoose.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, date, mongoose

I am attempting to update a field in an existing document with the current Date. I found an answer suggesting the use of $currentDate. I attempted:

```
var x = Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
    documentID,
    {$currentDate: {'lastUpdated':true}},
    {new :true},
    function(e,d){x = arguments})
```

The document returns just fine, the other changes I make are present, but the date does not go through.

The Schema is defined as

```
lastUpdated: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
```

x.lastUpdated is empty (not even null, just blank);
Prior to attempting the $currentDate method, I also tried the following for the update object:

```
lastUpdated: Date
lastUpdated: Date()
lastUpdated: new Date
lastUpdated: new Date()
lastUpdated: Date.now()
lastUpdated: Date().toISOString()
lastUpdated: new Date().toISOString();
```

OMG::: So the problem was in the way the return objects were being displayed. x.lastUpdated returned blank or displayed blank when called in the CLI because it was a Date instance (which also returns an empty line when entered into the console). BUT, console.log(x.lastUpdated) printed the date  properly. I realized this when i noticed that console.log()'ing the data in the callback would display the date normally, but calling the data object in the command line did not. Checking the document on mongoLab.com confirmed that the dates were in fact present all along. Well, there goes 3 hours of my life... Glad it got figured though :)

Edited::: to clarify the difference between console.log()'ing the object vs calling the object in the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date Instances display blank when called in the CLI. You have to console.log the date object to see its information displayed.

Comment: That's no true. It would rather be the fault of your code, which you notably don't show in your question nor what you are calling an answer.

Comment: Already verified this: > x[1].lastUpdate // returns blank line ; > console.log(x[1].lastUpdate) //returns a printout of the date